# Firebase Storage Unhandled Exception: No object exists at the desired reference

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to delete a folder on Firebase Storage using flutter.
This is going to be used in tandem with a delete document reference of the user on Firebase Firestore. For some reason it can never detect the object at the given location

My storage system is as follows:

1. A folder name with the userId as its name
2. Files under that folder with an appropriate name

So for example: "XqVs5BUlXBlwUa3JrwCz/ProfileImage" would reference the ProfileImage under user XqVs5BUlXBlwUa3JrwCz.

This is my code for that.

```
    static deleteUser(String userId) async {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
        //print(storage.ref().child("$userId/ProfileImage"));
        await storage.ref().child(userId).delete();
      }
```

And this is the result that it returns:

```
    [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
    #0      FirebaseStorageHostApi.referenceDelete
    messages.pigeon.dart:436
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      MethodChannelReference.delete
    method_channel_reference.dart:43
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      UserService.deleteUser
    user_service.dart:64
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting a folder from Firebase Cloud Storage in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459136/deleting-a-folder-from-firebase-cloud-storage-in-flutter)

Comment: Cloud Storage doesn't really have folders, and there is no operation to delete them. It just has paths the look like folders. In order to remove all objects nested under a path prefix, you have to list the files and delete them individually.

Comment: So I tried to do that, but it would always throw an object not found exception. That's what I can't wrap my head around. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have new code that lists and deletes objects like I recommend, you should post a new question with the new code and state what's not working the way you expect.  Listing objects shouldn't return anything that can't be deleted, unless something else deleted it first.