# How to clear firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I am building a web app with flutter, and I want to be able to clear the complete Firebase Storage with a buttonpress. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can simply call `delete()` on a document or collection. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#removing-data

Comment: But doesn't that only work for firebase? I want to use it in firebase storage.

Comment: Ah, I see, my bad. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: OKay, thanks anyway!

Comment: From looking around, it doesn't seem to be possible to delete an entire directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215897/4571656 There's no mention of it either in the documentation, just single file deletion. You may have to get a list of files and delete them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK doesn't provide any options to remove all objects from a storage bucket.  If you want to do this in your app, you will need to find each object using a [StorageReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference-class.html) object, then call [delete()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/delete.html) on each one individually.

Since the Flutter SDK [currently lacks a way to list files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603690/flutter-list-of-files-in-a-folder-in-firebase-cloud-storage) in a bucket, you might be helped by storing a reference to each file in a database, and querying the database to find each one to delete.

If you just want to manually clear the bucket during testing, you might find it easier to simply do that in the Firebase console.